# slick: what type do I need get back to iterate though a list in a view

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

The code below works find to show the most recent post by a user, but now I would like to get all the posts created by a user. How could I implement that?

What is confusing me is that the type that I am supposed to get back. It is Future[Option[Seq[Blog]]] or Future[Seq[Option[Blog]] or is there any better solutions?

```
  def find(user: User): Future[Option[Blog]] = {
    val blogQuery = blogs.filter(_.userID === user.userID.toString).sortBy(_.createdAt.desc)

     db.run(blogQuery.result.headOption).map { dbBlogOption =>
       dbBlogOption.map {
         dbBlog => Blog(None, dbBlog.title, dbBlog.content, UUID.fromString(dbBlog.userID), DateTime.parse(dbBlog.createdAt))
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just leave out the `.headOption` and you'll get a Future[Seq[Blog]] .
Note that it can be empty if none found, thus you don't need an Option.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, and the code nicely worked without an Option like you said, but now I am wondering what is the point of using `.headOption` in the first place to retrieve one post from an entire list. I mean, Future[Seq[DbBlog]] should be good enough as a result type, instead of Future[Option[Blog]]. If that’s the case, you just need to use `.head` not `.headOption`. Is that just a convention?  (I wrote the code myself, but based on some tutorial.)

Comment: Good :) if you do .head to get the first element and there is no such element if will throw a not found exception - which you can catch in a .recover block. In many cases where you're pretty sure it exists that's totally fine. But if you're not sure then the .headOption is better style.